# getting session variables from session

Tags: java, enumeration

I am getting  the below error when I compile the below code

```
Enumeration e = bean.getSession().getAttributeNames(); 
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) { 
        String name = (String)e.nextElement(); 
        String value = session.getAttribute(name).toString(); 
        System.out.println(name + " = " + value);
```

---

```
Error:
found   : java.util.Iterator
required: java.util.Enumeration
        Enumeration e = bean.getSession().getAttributeNames();
```

Comment: What is `bean`?  What does `getSession()` return?

Comment: It looks like you're using the old `Enumeration` type when you should be using the newer `Iterator` type.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using an enumeration, it should be an Iterator. Then use the methods of the Iterator like hasNext() to check if there is a next item and next() to get the next item. Hope it helps :)

Comment: No worries (: Just hoping to help out (:

Answer (score 3):

how about just using a for loop?

```
for (String name : bean.getSession().getAttributeNames() ) {
    String value = session.getAttribute(name).toString();
    System.out.println( name + " = " + value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're actually using a `getAttributeNames()` method that return an instance of `java.util.Iterator`. So as a quick fix, this should work:

```
Iterator it = bean.getSession().getAttributeNames(); 
while (it.hasNext()) { 
    String name = (String)it.next(); 
    String value = session.getAttribute(name).toString(); 
    System.out.println(name + " = " + value);
```

More help/info could be provided if we knew the actual types of the `bean` variable and/or the return value of `bean.getSession()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the first line. This works for me:

```
<%
    Enumeration attrs = session.getAttributeNames(); //you will need to include java.util.Enumeration
    while(attrs.hasMoreElements()){ //for each item in the session array
        String id = attrs.nextElement().toString(); //the name of the attribute
        out.print("'" + id + "': '" + session.getAttribute(id) + "'"); //print out the key/value pair
    }
%>
```

As others pointed out though, you should be using an Iterator